# LINQ to SQL debug visualizer for VS 2012?

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, visualizer

I'm looking for the Linq to SQL debug visualizer for VS 2012.

I found out that you needed to import `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll` in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizer

But I only found these 4 dll's:
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DataSetVisualizer.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.WpfTreeVisualizer.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Common
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Debugger

None of the above are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0` directory.

Comment: Thanks,forgot I had a search function in Windows. :p